# this.method Is not function with setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have this simple code:

```js
var Modules = (function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        
        TIMER: function (){
            var timer = null;
            
            return {
                time: 100,
                init: function() {
   
                    this.counter();
                    this.timer = window.setInterval(this.counter, 1000);
                },
                counter: function() {
                    this.time -= 1;

                    if (this.time <= 0) {
                        window.clearInterval(this.timer);
                        alert('Time expired');
                    }
                    console.log(this.time);
                    this.viewer();
                    
                },
                viewer: function() {
                    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = this.time;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}());

Modules.TIMER().init();
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

And something is wrong because I got 2 errors:

> this.viewer is not a function

and

> NaN of this.time

What it wrong with my design pattern running over interval?

After extend TIMER to reset method:

```
reset: function() {
                    this.time = 100;
                }
```

and call it outside as: 
`Modules.TIMER().reset();` ?

I got

> this.time is not defined

.

Or inside init:

```
jQuery("body").on('keyup mouseup', function (e) {
                        this.reset();
                    });
```

I got error:

> this.reset() is not s function.

Comment: OK I made getter and setter for variable, moved reset function as private and now is possible reset it. Still I cannot reset it from outside call by: Modules.TIMER().reset();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your issue is coming from this line:

```
this.timer = window.setInterval(this.counter, 1000);
```

When you are invoking the callback in the `setInterval` method, the `this` in the callback function no longer refers to your `TIMER` object, but the `window`.

---

### Solution A: Use `.bind(this)` to bind lexical `this` to callback

You will need to bind the current context to the callback:

```
this.timer = window.setInterval(this.counter.bind(this), 1000);
```

```js
var Modules = (function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        
        TIMER: function (){
            var timer = null;
            
            return {
                time: 100,
                init: function() {
   
                    this.counter();
                    this.timer = window.setInterval(this.counter.bind(this), 1000);
                },
                counter: function() {
                    this.time -= 1;

                    if (this.time <= 0) {
                        window.clearInterval(this.timer);
                        alert('Time expired');
                    }
                    console.log(this.time);
                    this.viewer();
                    
                },
                viewer: function() {
                    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = this.time;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}());

Modules.TIMER().init();
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

---

### Solution B: Use ES6 arrow function in `setInterval` callback

*Note: Personally, I prefer this solution because it uses ES6, but if you are still supporting legacy browsers and do not want to transpile your JS, this might not be the best solution.*

Another alternative will be using an arrow function in the callback of `setInterval`, instead of assigning the `this.counter` function as the callback directly:

```
this.timer = window.setInterval(() => this.counter(), 1000);
```

The arrow function preserves the lexical `this`, so when `this.counter()` is invoked it will be using the same context, i.e. the internal `this` will be referencing your `TIMER` object.

```js
var Modules = (function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        
        TIMER: function (){
            var timer = null;
            
            return {
                time: 100,
                init: function() {
   
                    this.counter();
                    this.timer = window.setInterval(() => this.counter(), 1000);
                },
                counter: function() {
                    this.time -= 1;

                    if (this.time <= 0) {
                        window.clearInterval(this.timer);
                        alert('Time expired');
                    }
                    console.log(this.time);
                    this.viewer();
                    
                },
                viewer: function() {
                    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = this.time;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}());

Modules.TIMER().init();
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found answer for reset from outside.
I changed TIMER like this:

```
TIMER: (function (){
    // all stuff
}())
```

Then call is like: `Modules.TIMER.reset();` and then it works as expected.